# UI is not created when .map() is used in .map() in react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

Using the react-leaflet library, I try to create each maker by recalling the arrays in one array.
In this process, we tried to use the data of the array in the array using .map() twice.
The data is confirmed through console.log(), but no marker was actually generated.
It was confirmed that a marker was created when A was used once.
I don't know why this is happening.

```
{UseSerial && SatLineView && sirialSatInfo.map((info) => {
                    return < View_range key={info.id}
                        position={[info.lat, info.lng]}
                        state={info.range}
                        id={info.id}
                        eventHandlers={{ click: () => View_Satellite_range(info.id) }}
                    />
                })}
```

Marker is handsome in the above case where he wrote .map() once.

```
{!UseSerial && SatLineView && noneSirialSatInfo.map((data) => {
                    data.data.map((info) => {
                        console.log(info.lat, info.lng)
                        return <Marker position={[30,0]}/>
                    })
                    return <Marker position={[0,0]}/>
                })}
```

However, if .map() was used twice as above, a marker was not created.

Answer (score 1):

map returns an array, in your example you don't do anything with this new array.

```js
noneSirialSatInfo.map((data) => {
  return data.data.map((info) => {
    return <Marker position={[info.lat, info.lng]} />;
  });
});
```